# Switching to Gatling for Load Testing

Tags: rest, load-testing, wadl, gatling

I'd like to use [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/) for REST performance and scalability web service testing. I'm currently using JMeter for this as I wasn't aware of gatling when I started this project. Gatling would integrate better and would be better for the project a number of reasons.

I'd like to ask one main question:

Obviously, there's a lot of overhead in configuring Gatling with the correct web service information. I've already done this in JMeter and I'm not keen to do it again. For one of the sub-projects, we have a WADL but we have no such thing for the other. Is it possible, out of the box, to import:

a. JMeter test plans and
b. WADL documents

into Gatling?

I've looked through the docs but unfortunately I can't find anything that references these.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Gatling has neither.

Building a jmx converter is something we might investigate in 2013, as you're not the first one to ask for it. At this point, I'm a bit skeptical, as the logic and the configuration of the 2 JMeter and Gatling are quite different, so the features and the way to use them don't map 1:1.

The easiest way to work with REST APIs is to use the recorder, so you'd dump request bodies as template and then inject data into them. See http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/http/http_request.html#request-body

If you work with JSON, you can use our JsonPath (or standard regex) checks in order to make assertions on the response body, or even capture data. See http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/http/http_check.html#defining-the-check-type

Comment: I suspected that about the JMX conversion. I considered writing a script to extract URIs and post bodies from the jmx test plan and dump them into gatling methods but quickly abandoned it as too time-consuming for my current needs. It's something to consider for the future though.

Comment: There's a much easier solution than parsing the jmx in order to extract the URIs and the bodies can help you. Have you considered pluging the Gatling Recorder as a proxy on Jmeter and just run it with one thread?

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I'll definitely try this.

Comment: It is 2014, is there support for load testing REST services?

Answer (score 0):

Using HttpSampler with Raw Post body And last 2.8 version is the right way to test Webservices.

Is it the way you are doing it ?
Upcoming  2.9 has new performance improvements related to memory and cpu consumed by Post Processors.

Regarding a, I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I'm doing it. The problem is that there are about 150 services and they each need to be hand-configured, added to which, Jmeter's scripting modules are a pretty convoluted affair. The test plans are clearly not designed to be hand-written, forcing users to deal with the GUI.